# Byte Array to Decimal Java

Tags: java

I have a Individual class that has the follow code

```
public class Individual {

    static int DNA_lenght = 64;
    private int fitness = 0;

    private byte[] genes = new byte[DNA_lenght];

    public void initialise_individual(){

        for(int i = 0; i < DNA_lenght; i++){

            byte gene = (byte) Math.round(Math.random());
            genes[i] = gene;
        }

    }
}
```

how can I write a method to translate the whole value of the individual into a decimal value?

Comment: What are you trying to do really? Your code looks wrong and bizarre in many ways (usage of Math.random() for one). Why would you turn DNA data (apparently) into a single decimal value?

Comment: Im trying to write a genetic algorithm and the use of Math.random() is creating a random individual with a array of random chromosomes

Comment: If I am not wrong, you want to convert genes array to one deimal value?

Comment: Except that it doesn't. All of your bytes (=8 bits) are either 00000000 or 00000001. What you really want is a byte in the range 0-255. You should use Random.nextBytes(byte[] genes) to create your genes. (Generates random bytes and places them into a user-supplied byte array. The number of random bytes produced is equal to the length of the byte array.)

Comment: But I want to store binary data in the byte array so this should be ok, isnt it?

Comment: Your question is not clear. How do you want to convert individual to decimal value?

Comment: @Meraman exactly, You got it

Comment: You can't store 64 bytes in any type of primitive data types(int, long, double). If I am not wrong, you want to store 64 bits to decimal.

Comment: You may be mistaken. Bytes are 8 bits, not 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want to create a random array of bytes. But what you are currently doing is generating a random array of 0 and 1 bytes (not bits). All of your bytes (=8 bits) are either 00000000 or 00000001. What you really want is a byte in the range 0-255. You should use [Random.nextBytes(byte[] genes)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextBytes%28byte%5B%5D%29) to create your genes.

> Generates random bytes and places them into a user-supplied byte array. The number of random bytes produced is equal to the length of the byte array.)

Then you want to convert this back into a decimal. However, as soon as you have more than 4 bytes, the values will no longer fit into a 32-bit (=4 byte) integer. If you have more than 8 bytes, they won't fit into a 64-bit integer etc.

For conversion, I'd use the [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) class. It takes care of the conversion for you, so you don't have to deal with [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

So, assuming you want a random gene of 64 **bits**, you do this as follows:

```
public static void main( String args[] ){
      // create random object
      Random r = new Random();

      int numBits = 64;
      int numBytes = numBits/8;

      // create the byte array
      byte[] genes = new byte[numBytes];

      //fill it
      r.nextBytes(genes);

      //print it
      System.out.println("byte array: " + genes);

      //now convert it to a 64-bit long using BigInteger          
      long l = new BigInteger(bytes).longValue();

      //print it
      System.out.println("long: " + l);
  }
```

Of course, you could also generate a random long value directly, by using:

```
Random r = new Random();
long longGenes = r.nextLong();
```

And convert that to a byte array if you really need one:

```
byte[] genes = new BigInteger(longGenes).toByteArray();
```

Comment: This is great, what about conversion to int?

Comment: Added it using the BigInteger class. You can do the conversion byte-by-byte yourself, but then you have more code and you need to take care of [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). That's why the easiest way is to just use BigInteger. For a 32bit array you would use BigInteger.intValue().

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, why is `length` spelled `lenght`?

Secondly, this will fill the array with zeros, which I presume is not what you want.

```
    for(int i = 0; i < DNA_lenght; i++){

        byte gene = (byte) Math.round(Math.random());
        genes[i] = gene;
    }
```

Instead try something like:

```
    genes = new byte[64];
    new Random().nextBytes(genes);
```

Finally, you cannot uniquely convert a byte array of length 64 (so 512 bits) into a decimal value (`double` is only 64 bits).

**Update**

After reading the question's comments, I am lead to believe you want convert 64 **bits** into a decimal value. That is possible, and can be simply done with `new Random().nextLong()`, or if you insist on using the byte data type:

```
genes = new byte[8];
// fill with random values
new Random().nextBytes(genes);
// convert to long
long decimalValue;
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    decimalValue <<= 8;
    decimalValue += genes[i] & 0xff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think BigInteger is more appropriate. There is a random generation such as constructor `java.math.BigInteger.BigInteger(int numBits, Random rnd)`. Also there are constructor from byte array and `toByteArray` method.